# automapper project into a larger object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

With [Automapper](http://automapper.org/), is it possible to project a smaller object onto a larger one?

For example, a controller accepts data as a ViewModel instance. I would then need to create a record in a database. So I would project this View Model onto a Domain Model. Once I have a Domain Model instance populated with View Model data I would then manually populate the additional fields in the Domain Model before storing data in the database.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly possible. Just create a mapping from the ViewModel to the domain model and use [`Ignore()`](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration%20Validation) to ignore non-existing properties:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyOnDomainModel, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Small example:

```
public ActionResult Register(UserModel model)
{
    User user = Mapper.Map<User>(model);    
    user.Password = PasswordHelper.GenerateHashedPassword();
    _db.Users.Add(user);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

With this configured mapping:

```
CreateMap<UserModel, User>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

This makes sure that the password won't be overridden by AutoMapper.