# I'm trying to map a collection from my domain object to a dto object using an automapper, but I fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**Domain object**

```
namespace Blog.Domain
{
    public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
}
```

**Dto object**

```
namespace Blog.Application.DataTransfer
{
    public class CategoryDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Profile**

```
namespace Blog.Api.Core.Profiles
{
    public class CategoryProfile : Profile
    {
        public CategoryProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();
            CreateMap<CategoryDto, Category>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the category, I fetched information about the category and the posts that belong to this category, but mapping does not work. How to solve it? Do I need a .ForMember to map collections?

```
public class EfGetOneCategoryQuery : IGetOneCategoryQuery
{
    private readonly BlogContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public EfGetOneCategoryQuery(BlogContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public CategoryDto Execute(int search)
    {
        var category = _context.Categories.Include(x => x.Posts).Where(x => x.Id == search).FirstOrDefault();

        if (category == null)
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(search, typeof(CategoryDto));
        }

        var response = _mapper.Map<CategoryDto>(category);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will need to provide details on what the actual error is you are getting.  We don't even know for sure yet if it is a compilation error or runtime error.

Comment: Please share your error code

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to map from an object with an Id to one without an Id and thus, Automapper gets confused. You should use `opt.Ignore()` in you mapping.
Refer to [automapper project into a larger object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661657/automapper-project-into-a-larger-object)

Or you could move the Id from the Dto to the domain object instead.
and next time, ensure to add more details of the error that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of information. This is my first time posting. I solved this using:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Posts, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Posts.Select(x => new PostDto { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Description = x.Description, CategoryId = x.CategoryId, ImageId = x.ImageId })));
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Id from Dto? But if you truly need it, then this should work:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>( )
        .ForMember(x => x.Id, m => m.Ignore())
```

2nd option:

```
public class CategoryDto
{
    [IgnoreMap]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```